# Defining Multiple IPs for a check

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm really not sure how to word the title. What i'm trying to do: I have a table in Mysql that has a column in it for for IPs i've added. I don't want a player to connect to my server if there IP is in my table.
Table looks like this as a example:

```
    #  |  IP
    1  | 127.0.0.1
    2  | 128.0.0.1
    3  | 129.0.0.1
    4  | 130.0.0.1
```

I want to, with C#, make it so it checks if the person connecting's ip is on that then stop the connection. I have the players IP already defined, it's plr.Account.IP as a example. How exactly do I define every IP in the database to check? I've tried a couple ways but have failed, I'm still pretty new to this side of coding, and am just looking for some help. :)

EDIT:

Alright, sorry, I guess I worded it wrong. I'm in a dev group for a small game (It's mainly practice for me so I can get better.) I removed what I was trying to do because it failed miserably and I couldn't rebuild with it there. I probably should of commented it out but I didn't see it worth it. I'm trying to make something like this

```
           If(player.Account.IP == BannedIP) 
    {
     //banned
    }
```

Something like that. BannedIP would be any of the IPs from MySQL that I put on there. I'm trying what Apomene posted now.

Comment: It would more convenient if you'd provide the piece of code where you're reading the record(s). I'll be able to help you much faster and more accurate.

Comment: Please post your code with what you are currently doing.

Comment: Are you asking how to query a MySQL database from C#? or how to form a lookup query in SQL? - Best to add your best attempt so far and explain why its not doing what you want it to,

Comment: Apart from what @DriesVB said, why would you control max player logged in via IP counts? Why not just block login if (AccountIsLoggedIn) ?

Comment: Alright, sorry, I guess I worded it wrong. I'm in a dev group for a small game (It's mainly practice for me so I can get better.) I removed what I was trying to do because it failed miserably and I couldn't rebuild with it there. I probably should of commented it out but I didn't see it worth it. I'm trying to something like this 
`If(player.Account.IP == BannedIP)
{
break;
}
`
Something like that. BannedIP would be any of the IPs from MySQL that I put on there.

Comment: You seem to be thinking in reverse; "push" the users IP don't "pull" the list. You would execute a `select exists(select * from ips where ip='userip')` statement to have the DB look for the ip in the table then act upon the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Ips WHERE ip=@playerip", MySqlConn.conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playerip", plr.Account.IP);
cmd.Prepare();
MySqlDataReader res = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (res.HasRows)
{
     // banned
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at the start of your program save the IPs in a list:

```
 List <string> IPs=new List<string>();
 MySqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("yourconnectionstring");
 conn.Open();   
  MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
  string command = "Select IP from myIPTable";
  cmd.CommandText = command;
  MySqlDataReader sqlreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (sqlreader.Read())
    {
      IPs.Add(sqlreader[0].ToString());
    }
```

Afterwards you can check if user can use the conection:

```
...
if (IPs.Contains(plr.Account.IP)
{
  ///dont allow use to make any actions
}
```